# How to run artisan command in background Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, daemon, digital-ocean, daemons

I am trying with putty below command and its working

```
php artisan horizon
```

But if I close ssh (putty) this command automatically shut down.

I want to run this command always in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You have some options for run some process in background :

1. Using & : php artisan horizon &
2. Using nohup : nohup php artisan horizon (but you don't need this option)
3. Using systemctl : create a service (but you don't need this option)

in your case the first option is the best.

Comment: Thanks first one is working. Can you please guide me about the termination of this command if in future I want to stop this command.

Comment: $ ps aux | grep php
then you can see the pid of you command and then run
$ kill -9 pid

Comment: maybe your process is finished.

Comment: this command php artisan horizon & working in the background until putty is working but I want this command work always run in the background after I close putty.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `&` at the end of the command to put the process background.

`php artisan horizon &`

Comment: Can you please guide me about the termination of this command if in future I want to stop this command.

Comment: You can use `fg` to get the last background command into the foreground and `Ctrl+c` to terminate it.

Comment: this command php artisan horizon & working in the background until putty is working but I want this command work always run in the background after I close putty.